# Jobs missing links to company profile

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

I want to hide the jobs of a company, partly because they are completely irrelevant to my tech stack and mostly because of the horrible need to UPPERCASE the HIRING word as if anyone cared about it.

This is one of those jobs: [AGODA HIRING: Assistant Supply Innovation Manager - Tokyo](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/189453/agoda-hiring-assistant-supply-innovation-manager-big-wednesday-digital)

As you can see from there, there is a link to the company's website but there is not a single link to the Stack Overflow profile page.

I also tried to look manually for them, but either the search engine is broken or their name is not "agoda" nor "big wednesday digital"... or maybe they do not even have a profile?

Comment: Seems that for the job you linked, it's through an external agency, and they chose to link to the website instead of company page as there wasn't one. Also, the company section of the ad wasn't filled in, so the Company "tab" wasn't shown. Probably by-design?

Comment: @SamuelLiew That was what I was afraid of... How can I ignore the hundreds of jobs they have then?

Comment: We'll have to wait for the staff to take a look at your feature request

Comment: Does [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&cd=Big+Wednesday+Digital) help?

Comment: We'll need to look into enabling the job dismissal feature for companies using an external application provider

Comment: @DeanWard Not that I can see... I figured the company wasn't registered here. Thanks for looking at it!